# An atypical password validation regexp: at least 3 letters, 3 numbers, no double-quotes

Tags: regex, html, validation, input, passwords

This regexp is for an HTML5 `pattern="..."` within an `< input type="password" ... />` that should be:

1. No less than 8 chars, no more than 32.
2. Must contain at least 3 letters.
3. Must contain at least 3 numbers.
4. Must contain anything else that's ASCII except for double-quotes (single-quotes are fine).

This is what I've conjured:

**^.*(?=.{8,32})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{3,})(?=.*\d{3,})(?=.*[^\x22]+).*$**

But here are the problems:

1. Double-quotes are still allowed to be in password!
2. This expression will only match when there are three CONSECUTIVE numbers or letters and not when they are interspersed with other characters.

I've spent all day reading as much documentation humanly possible: O'Reilly's, online docs, etc., and I'm about to blow my brains out if I can't figure this out.

Any help would be incredibly grateful, and you will save a bullet and a brain.

Comment: There's a time to read documentations and there's a time to experiment yourself. The pattern you are looking for is not so complicated. I suggest you to take the time to exactly understand what means your actual pattern (in particular how lookahead works and the fact they are zero-width assertions at a specific position) and to experiment. (a link for that: http://www.regex101.com ). Take a look at other password/regex questions too. Good luck.

Comment: Try `^(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3})(?=(?:\D*\d){3})[^\x22]{8,32}$`

Comment: Thanks, @stribizhev ! This is very similar to anubhava's example but includes the \x22 needed for escaping the double-quote. -- Edited: -- And what is the difference between (?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]) and (?:.*?[a-zA-Z])?

Comment: Complex password rules will usually not lead to more safe passwords, important is only a minimum length. People cannot remember tons of strong passwords, and such rules can interfere with good password schemes. People can get very inventive to bypass such rules, e.g. by using weak passwords like `Password-2015`. Often you end up with weaker passwords instead of stronger ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=(?:.*?[a-zA-Z]){3})(?=(?:.*?\d){3})[^\x22]{8,32}$
```

[ReGEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC9gV9/6)

Or even:

```
^(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z]){3})(?=(?:[^\d\n]*\d){3})[^\x22]{8,32}$
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, @anubhava . Can you please edit [^"] to [^\x22] because this needs to be placed within an HTML5 pattern="" and we need to work within double-quotes. What are your thoughts on stribizhev's and my comment above?

Comment: Ok answer updated. `^(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3})(?=(?:\D*\d){3})[^\x22]{8,32}$` may also work but on regex101 you will need to make it `^(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z]){3})(?=(?:\D*\d){3})[^\x22]{8,32}$` as you have multiple inputs and `[^a-zA-Z]*` also matches newlines so it goes across lines. **Check my updated demo link in answer**

Comment: So shortest working regex would be: `^(?=(?:.*?[a-zA-Z]){3})(?=(?:.*?\d){3})[^\x22]{8,32}$` but will be slight less efficient.

Comment: Wow, these make complete sense now and I see what I was doing wrong. Thank you @anubhava for helping me understand this language better!

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this thing:

```
^(?=(.*?[a-zA-Z]){3,})(?=(.*?\d){3,})(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9\"])[^\"]{8,32}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/nY0bL2/1 - for testing rewrite the first line, multilines don't work well for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the effort. You're right, this doesn't work without a space or newline in the string.